# Application of fixed point theory in Physics

Tags: physics, fixed-point-theorems

Is there any application of fixed point theory in Physics?

Comment: Certainly, fixed point theorems are used for PDEs, which are used for physics.

Comment: eigenvectors with eigenvalue one? For example, the axis of rotation for a rotation.

Comment: If you'd like to know what is used in Physics (as opposed to what mathematicians think is used in Physics), you should ask on [physics.se].

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Renormalization group equations, used both in particle physics and condensed matter physics, often have fixed points with implications for physics. One notable example is asymptotic freedom in QCD, which is based on the observation that the renormalization group equations for the gauge couplings (and the Yukawa couplings as well) have an ultraviolet (high energy) fixed point at zero coupling strength. In some theories, there are also infrared fixed point, or quasi-fixed points that predict particle masses (or mass ratios). You might start from the wikipedia article

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Renormalization_group

for more information.